Displaying table layout with table and column name referenced by foreign keys in Postgres
I have this query that works for version  14 of postgres, but doesn't work for version 15.
What it does is show the table name, column name, primary key and how it corresponds with it's foreign key.
Here is the query that works in V14, but not V15:
SELECT DISTINCT tc.table_schema "sc"
       , tc.table_name "tab1"
          , kcu.column_name "columnname"
             , tc.constraint_name "conname"
   ,CASE
    WHEN tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN 'R'
    WHEN tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    THEN 'P' END AS constrainttype
  , kcu.ordinal_position "position"
   , CASE WHEN tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN ccu.table_schema 
     END AS r_table_schema
   , CASE WHEN tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN ccu.table_name 
     END AS r_table_name
   , CASE WHEN tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN ccu.column_name 
     END AS r_column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
      AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
      AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
WHERE tc.table_schema = 's1'
;

Sample result: (P) Primary key, (R) foreign key



sc
table1
column_name
con_name
typ
Pos
table
column




s1
d1
d1_key
d1_pk
P
1




s1
d2
denm_key
c_denm_d2
R
1
denm
denm_key


s1
d2
d1_key
c_d1_d2
R
1
d1
d1_key


s1
d2
d2_key
d2_pk
P
1





s1
d2
vsubtype_key
c_vsubtype_d2
R
1
vsubtype
vsubtype_key


s1
d2
vtype_key
c_vtype_d2
R
1
vtype
vtype_key



Is there a way to make a result set like this easily in V15?

What should it do? And what is wrong? When I change the schema name and execute this on a V16 database, I get results.

Also, your query result does not match the query and is so ill-formatted that I cannot really parse it. Please put a little more love into the question.

It works on 16, 15 and 14 just fine. It even runs fine on everything all the way back to 9.3 but I don't see why it wouldn't even on a 7.4.
